# Merging the result rows into one in a oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have create a view using some 5 tables. The output data comes form almost all tables and have about 10 columns. The output is like the following:

```
EmployeeName   Addr    Dept
___________________________

Vishal         Pune    Finance
Vishal         Pune    null
Ahmed          Bombay  Admin
Ahmed          Bombay  Null
```

I need output as:

```
EmployeeName   Addr    Dept
___________________________

Vishal         Pune    Finance
Ahmed          Bombay  Admin
```

In above example, consider the columns shown are coming from different tables. Please suggest some solution

Comment: `Group By` Name and use `MAX(Addr)` and `MAX(Dept)`

Answer (score 0):

Just check if below is what you are trying to ask for?

```
WITH TAB1 AS 
( SELECT 'Vishal' ENAME, 'Pune' ADDR, 'Finance' DEPT FROM DUAL 
  UNION
  SELECT 'Vishal' ENAME, 'Pune' ADDR, NULL DEPT FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'Ahmed' ENAME, 'Bombay' ADDR, 'Admin' DEPT FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'Ahmed' ENAME, 'Bombay' ADDR, NULL DEPT FROM DUAL
) SELECT * FROM TAB1 WHERE DEPT IS NOT NULL;
```